# How to get textfile text to string variable action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to action script. How can I get input textfield value to string or any variable. my code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str:String = myTextField.text;
```

`TextField`s have a property known as `text`.  A property is not quite the same thing as a variable, but it's very similar; you can use it almost the same way.  Since a `TextField` object has a property called `text`, and since it is of type `String`, it's as simple as declaring a `String` variable, then assigning the property's value to that variable.